# How can I write files as a different user from IIS?

Tags: c, iis, permissions

I have an ISAPI Extension written in C. One of the functions it performs is to receive a file and write it to disk.

The extension runs as IUSR so I gave write access to IUSR. Instead I want to be able to give write access to specific users and use information passed from the client to write the file as that user.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the application pool identity.

1)Open iis manager

2)select your application pool-> advance setting.

3)in the application pool identity set custom user account or local system.

[image]

4)open the folder for which you want to set the permission and set the folder to write permission to the "IIS AppPool\yourapppoolname"

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use LogonUser, ImpersonateLoggedOnUser, and RevertToSelf. If the client app passes the domain/username/password, the server code can impersonate them.